# Develop five terms in the Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Develop five terms in the Taylor series around $x_0=\pi$ for the function $f(x)=\cos\left({x\over3}\right)$

$f^0(x)=\cos\left({x\over3}\right) \Big|_\pi $

$f^{'}(x)=-\sin\left({x\over3}\right) {1\over3} \Big|_\pi$

$f^{''}(x)=-\cos\left({x\over3}\right) {1\over9} \Big|_\pi$

$f^{'''}(x)=\sin\left({x\over3}\right) {1\over{27}} \Big|_\pi$

$f^{iv}(x)=\cos\left({x\over3}\right) {1\over{81}} \Big|_\pi$

So (...)

$S={\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right)}{-\sin\left({\pi\over3}\right) {1\over3}}{-\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right) {1\over9}}+{\sin\left({\pi\over3}\right) {1\over{27}}}+{\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right) {1\over{81}}}$

**EDIT: **

I forgot the factorial division and multiplication by $x_0$

$S=
{\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right)}-
{{1\over3}\sin\left({\pi\over3}\right)(x-\pi)}-
\frac{{1\over9}\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right) }{2}(x-\pi)^2+
\frac{{1\over{27}}\sin\left({\pi\over3}\right) }{6}(x-\pi)^3+
\frac{{1\over{81}}\cos\left({\pi\over3}\right) }{24}(x-\pi)^4$

My question is: this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. You forgot the factorial terms in the denominator, for one. You forgot the powers of $x-\pi,$ as well. Also, you should be able to explicitly evaluate those trigonometric expressions.

**Edit**: It looks better, but you can still evaluate those trig expressions and simplify those fractions. Also, I just realized that you incorrectly calculated your fourth derivative.

Comment: Look again, please

Comment: @Tomi: Answer updated.